# Transparency in Java.Robot.createScreenCapture

Tags: java, class, transparency, screenshot, alpha

Pretty much all I want to know is if there is any way that you can get alpha/transparency when taking a screenshot using java.robot.createScreenCapture()?

Answer (score 3):

No, not as far as I know. Honestly I don't think that it would make sense! Each pixel of your screen is opaque, i.e., completely filled with some color. (How would some pixel on your screen be transparent?)

Comment: Think about it like this there are windows that you have that could be transparent like Windows Aero transparency on windows 7 or with any number of widgets on Linux. When you do the screen capture they all come up with a black box behind them.

Comment: thats due to hardware acceleration. it is generally really hard to cature such screenshots. you basically need to do it on the driver level.

Comment: @OP:  Thanks for clarifying the requirement & perceived failings of `Robot`.  I had thought much the same as aioobe must have, when reading your initial question.  Could you grab a screen shot, trim it down to just enough to see the effect, post it at an image site and drop us a link?  I'd like to see what you mean with my own eyes, and might embed it in your question if it is small enough in bytes.